# What does the following code fragment (in C) print?

Tags: c, printf, fragment

What does the following code fragment (in C) print?

```
int a = 033;
printf("%d", a + 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? That's usually the best way to find out. Asking *why* is a different matter.

Comment: thanks Cody, I was just needing a "fast answer". Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`033` is an ***octal integer literal*** and its value is `8*3+3 = 27`. Your code prints `28`.

An integer literal that starts with a `0` is octal. If it starts in `0x` it's hexadecimal.

By the way, for an example's sake

```
int x = 08; //error
```

is a compile-time error since `8` is not an octal digit.

Answer (score 0):

I would risk a wild guess and say `28` :)

Comment: thanks mingos and darioo. I would like to know how to close this post

Answer (score 0):

28.

033 is an octal number in C because it has a leading "0" and that means its value is 27 in decimal.

So, 27 + 1 = 28

Answer (score 0):

here's a cue:

- a 3-digit with zero in the beginning is an octal.
- a 2-digit value with "0x" in the beginning is a hex.

Try looking at this example:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 main()
 {
 int a = 033;
 printf("\nin decimal: %d", a+1);
 printf("\nin hex: %x", a+1);
 printf("\nin octal: %o", a+1);
 }
```

this results in:

```
in decimal: 28
in hex: 1c
in octal: 34
```